# program for A three-point Gauss integration

Tags: java, integration, gaussian

I want to write a java program to calculate integral with three-point Gauss.
How to calculate result of every function that is string?
For example want to calculate `F(x) = x^4 + cos(x) + e^2x`

Comment: What is your problem exactly? How to parse the function from string to "real operation"?

Comment: I can't give a better answer than the already given ones. You need a parser to build some kind of an expression tree. Some good tutorials are available on the net. A really good and compact example can be found in Bjarne Stroustrup's c++ book (though it's c++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluating a string is not an easy task by itself.

You have to write your own [Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29) with [Lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and a [Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser).

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use thirdparty libraries for mathematical functions parsing and execution. I've never used any one of them. Simple googling reveals this:

[JbcParser](http://www.bestcode.com/html/jbcparser.html)

[JepParser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jep/)

I'm sure there are a couple of others around...

Hope this helps